# Set up globally accessable NAS using Apache or other programs

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, openvpn, nas, samba

I have a 400gb SSD which I've connected to my Raspberry pi, and set up as a Samba Nas server. It works great when I'm at home, but my ISP blocked ports 445 and 136-139, so I also set up an OpenVPN server so that I can access it outside.

However, when using public computers or school computers I can't use the OpenVPN client, so I also set up an Apache server, where I can easily access and download my files (with authentication of course) from any browser anywhere.

The problem is that I still can't upload my files without FTP or SCP, so how would I add the ability to upload, rename, and delete files in Apache or is there another way I can have an easily accessible file server where I can upload, change, and delete files?

Comment: If you want to upload files with Apache that would require a .NET or PHP website.  If you do it wrong which is easy to do you risk exposing your NAS to the world.  Use a portable SSH program like putty or something similar instead.  You could also just the port SSH runs on instead of using an insecure option like Apache.

Comment: Is there any simple portable SCP gui for MacOS? I'm not too familiar with Macs so I'm not sure how portable programs work or if they even exist at all

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no mention of MacOS

Comment: I originally wanted the NAS to be accessible through the browser, if that's not feasible on Windows I can run WinSCP portable on a flash drive, but I'm not too sure about MacOS

Comment: It’s feasible but it’s extremely insecure.  You need to specify Windows or MacOS.  Software recommendations are out of scope.  It’s not clear why you can’t simply change the port on the SSH server and connect the client through SSH bypassing the OpenVPN

Comment: I use both Windows and Mac computers daily, Samba doesn't seem to like using any ports besides 139 and 445. Since I can't install a client on the computers, for Windows I can run a portable SCP gui like WinSCP which uses SSH, but I'm not sure how to do this on a Mac.

Comment: I am suggesting you change the OpenSSH port.  So you can do secure file transfers.  FTP through Apache is insecure